# How do make a count down inside the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit, settimeout

I want to make a 5-second countdown inside my button so you can see how much time is left before I submit some content after I click the button. I get the value he has to count down from "data-delay" inside my HTML tag

```javascript
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Demo of what I assume you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp99cw3q/2/

Firstly,

```
var b = $(button);
```

is invalid, I assume you're wanting to access the button attributes, so use:

```
var b = $('#first');
```

This then allows you to use b to access everything you need, eg:

```
var text = b.attr('value');
```

if you want the timer function to be called on click:

```
$('#first').click(function() {
    timer();
});
```

which I would then set up as so:

```
function timer(){   
   setTimeout(function(){
       b.val(text + ' ' + counter);   // update the text with the counter
       b.attr('data-delay', counter); // update the attribute holding the value
       if (counter == 0) {next();}    // if finished, call next function
       else {counter--; timer();}     // decrease the counter and call the timer again after 1s
   },1000);
}

function next() {
    b.val('Done!');
    //whatever happens afterwards
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the updated/working code.**

```
<input type="button" value="Submit and wait!" id="first" data-delay="5"></input>


var button = $('#first');
var counter = button.attr('data-delay');
var text = button.attr('value');
function timer() {
    button.val(text+' '+counter);
    if (counter == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        button.val("TimeOut");
    } else {
        counter--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```